# Spawn processes using host file with mpi4py

Tags: python, spawn, mpi4py

I'm trying to spawn a set of worker processes across several hosts using MPI4py and OpenMPI, but the spawn command seems to ignore my host file. I've posted [my full test](https://gist.github.com/donkirkby/eec37a7cf25f89c6f259), but here are the key parts:

Based on [a forum discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mpi4py/kY43v2fKW2I/6hMImN-6p-8J), my manager script calls spawn with the `hostfile` option:

```
mpi_info = MPI.Info.Create()
mpi_info.Set("hostfile", "worker_hosts")

comm = MPI.COMM_SELF.Spawn(sys.executable,
                           args=['testworker.py'],
                           maxprocs=args.worker_count,
                           info=mpi_info).Merge()
```

In the `worker_hosts` file, I list the nodes in my Scyld Beowulf cluster:

```
myhead1 slots=2
mycompute1 slots=2
mycompute2 slots=2
mycompute3 slots=2
mycompute4 slots=3
```

The manager and the workers all call `MPI.Get_processor_name()`, but they all report "myhead1". If I use the same host file with `mpirun` it works:

```
> mpirun -hostfile worker_hosts -np 3 python -c "from mpi4py import MPI; print MPI.Get_processor_name()"
myhead1
myhead1
mycompute1
```

If I change the name of the host file to something that doesn't exist, like `bogus_file`, I get an error:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Open RTE was unable to open the hostfile:
    bogus_file
Check to make sure the path and filename are correct.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
[Bulbasaur:86523] [[3458,0],0] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Not found in file base/rmaps_base_support_fns.c at line 83
[Bulbasaur:86523] [[3458,0],0] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Not found in file rmaps_rr.c at line 82
[Bulbasaur:86523] [[3458,0],0] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Not found in file base/rmaps_base_map_job.c at line 88
[Bulbasaur:86523] [[3458,0],0] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Not found in file base/plm_base_launch_support.c at line 105
[Bulbasaur:86523] [[3458,0],0] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Not found in file plm_rsh_module.c at line 1173
```

So OpenMPI has noticed the `hostfile` option, it just doesn't seem to use it. The `hostfile` option is listed in the [OpenMPI documentation](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.4/man3/MPI_Comm_spawn.3.php#sect7).

```
Key                   Type      Description
---                   ----      -----------
host                  char *    Host on which the process should be spawned.
                                See the orte_host man page for an
                                explanation of how this will be used.
hostfile              char *    Hostfile containing the hosts on which
                                the processes are to be spawned. See
                                the orte_hostfile man page for an
                                explanation of how this will be used.
```

How can I specify the host file for a spawn request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a more recent version of the [OpenMPI documentation](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.8/man3/MPI_Comm_spawn.3.php#sect7) that gave me the magic option:

```
Key                    Type     Description
---                    ----     -----------
host                   char *   Host on which the process should be
                                spawned.  See the orte_host man
                                page for an explanation of how this
                                will be used.
hostfile               char *   Hostfile containing the hosts on which
                                the processes are to be spawned. See
                                the orte_hostfile man page for
                                an explanation of how this will be
                                used.
add-host               char *   Add the specified host to the list of
                                hosts known to this job and use it for
                                the associated process. This will be
                                used similarly to the -host option.
add-hostfile           char *   Hostfile containing hosts to be added
                                to the list of hosts known to this job
                                and use it for the associated
                                process. This will be used similarly
                                to the -hostfile option.
```

If I change to using `add-hostfile`, it works perfectly:

```
mpi_info.Set("add-hostfile", "worker_hosts")
```

If you're stuck using the older version of OpenMPI, try running the manager script with `mpirun` and the same hostfile. That also worked when I was still using the `hostfile` option.

```
mpirun -hostfile worker_hosts -np1 python testmanager.py
```

Comment: Is there a way to use the slots on the manager node? As when I run this the manager runs in isolation on a whole node, while the workers run on the others. If I try to ask for more workers than there are process on the non-manager nodes then it hangs.